# Como armazenar várias informações em JS adequadamente?

Tags: javascript

Eu preciso armazenar várias informações em um objeto ou *array*, o código está assim, adicionando as informações por `push()`:

```js
let filaDeEspera = {nome:[], telefone:[], senha:[]}

filaDeEspera.nome.push("João")
filaDeEspera.telefone.push("1122223333")
filaDeEspera.senha.push("001")

//Adicionando outra pessoa
filaDeEspera.nome.push("Maria")
filaDeEspera.telefone.push("4455556666")
filaDeEspera.senha.push("002")

console.log(filaDeEspera)
```

Porém, além de ineficiente (repetição de código) eu preciso ficar procurando as informações pelo *index* do *array* a fim de deletar, existe uma melhor maneira de armazenar essas informações?

Comment: Não seria melhor ter um array de objetos em vez de ter um objetos com arrays?

Comment: Eu não sei na verdade, esta é a questão, como eu busco e deleto informações de objetos dentro de um array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seria melhor agrupar tudo em um objeto JSON. 
Para excluir você pode utilizar o método splice do javascript;
Para facilitar separei em funções.
Veja o exemplo abaixo.

```js
let filaDeEspera = [];

function addFilaEspera(item){
  filaDeEspera.push(item);
};


function removerFilaEsperaPorSenha(senha){
   let indiceRemover=null;

   //localiza item
   for(i=0; i<filaDeEspera.length ;i++){
      let item =  filaDeEspera[i];

      if(item.senha == senha){
        indiceRemover= i;
        break;
      }
   }
   //remove item 
   if(indiceRemover != null){
        filaDeEspera.splice(indiceRemover,1);
   }
   
}


addFilaEspera({
   nome: "João",
   telefone: "1122223333",
   senha: "001"
});

addFilaEspera({
   nome: "Maria",
   telefone: "4455556666",
   senha: "002"
});


console.log(filaDeEspera);
removerFilaEsperaPorSenha("001");
console.log(filaDeEspera);
```

Comment: Você pode usar o método [`Array.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) para localizar o item: `let indiceRemover = filaDeEspera.findIndex(obj => obj.senha === senha)`

Answer (score 4):

Geralmente nós, programadores, agrupamos os membros do objeto em algo único e não mantemos os membros separados. Assim, a fila seria composta de vários objetos que representam pessoas. Na forma atual sue código tem um objeto que possui filas isoladas com dados isolados de pessoas, parece conceitualmente errado.

```js
let filaDeEspera = [];
filaDeEspera.push({nome : "João", telefone : "1122223333", senha : "001"});
filaDeEspera.push({nome : "Maria", telefone : "4455556666", senha : "002"});
console.log(filaDeEspera);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Add.js).

Você poderia ainda adicionar já na criação do objeto do tipo *array*, mas por ser uma fila me parece que ocorrerá mais adições que um uso inicializado.

Se for uma aplicação muito complexa poderia criar alguma abstração para isso, mas parece que nem é o caso pelo pouco conhecimento que tem. Poderia manter uma estrutura para controlar melhor a criação do objeto dentro de um padrão.

Talvez tenha dificuldade com isso porque ainda não chegou no ponto de aprender essas coisas. Aí aconselho aprender o básico antes antes de partir para coisas mais complexas, e de preferência de forma mais estruturada e acompanhada já que ainda não possui conhecimento para direcionar os próprios estudos. Um exemplo de erro é o não uso de `;` no final da linha. Você acredita que está certo só porque não deu erro.

Comment: No Javascript o uso de `;` no fim da linha é opcional. Sempre foi considerado boa prática por conta das "minificações" que são feitas no arquivos JS, mas nesta época de _transpilers_ não faz diferença.

Comment: Na verdade tem várias situações que se deixar sem dá problema, mesmo não minificando.

Comment: Vai ver eu só não me deparei com elas então. :)  Mas de qualquer maneira, não diria que é um erro não usá-las.

Answer (score 2):

Pode ser feita com Objetos, e criar uma função para retornar um objeto, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
const filaDeEspera = []

const addPessoa = ( _nome, _telefone, _senha ) => {
  return {
    nome: _nome,
    telefone: _telefone,
    senha: _senha
  }
}

filaDeEspera.push( addPessoa( 'maria', '4455556666', '002' ) )
```

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma
Abraço